How to make and receive calls from second phone?
On a motorcycle, I have the following situation:
The Galaxy S23 has a SIM card and is connected to the motorcycle intercom. Phone is located in my pocket or tank bag.
The Galaxy S8 without a SIM card is permanently mounted on the motorcycle. It works as navigation.
Problem to solve: How to receive/make a call via the S23 on the S8.

Please edit your post with answers/details for the following: When you say "make/receive calls on S8" are you expecting to use the same mobile number as the S23? Is the S23 a WiFi hotspot for the S8? If the S23 is already paired with the motorcycle intercom (as opposed to a helmet headset) is there a user interface issue that you want to change. More details about your current setup and why it doesn't work would be helpful.

I would like to have a function on the S8 like in Android Auto, which allows me to receive and make calls on the S23 phone
